# how to get a file that contains a specific word in a folder?

Tags: python, windows, grep, memory-efficient

I would like to filter through files by a specific word that I pass like a argument.

These folders are located at Windows server and I'm using Python.

I have tried `findstr` but it's extremely slow, and I am looking for a efficient way to tackle this.

Comment: do you have some current code?

Comment: `popen("cmd /k findstr /M word_for_search "+ dir_path+"*").read())`

This code works but it's extremly slow !!! keep in mind I am talking about thousand of folders and thousand of files in each of them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want to issue this as a system command and use the Windows search, rather than re-inventing the search in Python.  From Python, invoke

```
status, result = commands.getstatusoutput(*windows_command*)
```

The particular command depends on which Windows system you're on.  Enter it as you would from the command line.  Using the UNIX command:

```
status, result = commands.getstatusoutput("grep -r " + word + " *")
if status == 0:
    print result
```